# how can i insert Record With Pushkey in firebase realtime

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database

unfornately i should insert record with parentid into  realtime databse in firebase

this is my sample added record in chat collection that messageId and key of parent is same

```
  "-N6w7t_jTLazBcbLnIau": {
  "content": "Test message 1",
  "fromId": "Yto2rkMyXJNVkWS3xAOJgUjXFzI3",
  "messageId": "-N6w7t_jTLazBcbLnIau",
  "phone": "+989034015019",
  "timestamp": "1657792676492",
  "toId": "0FXpksPdL4OAf9KAXx9B0R6nzmh2",
  "type": "1"
},
"-N6w8651yjmhOKRHd5xG": {
  "content": "Test massege 2",
  "fromId": "Yto2rkMyXJNVkWS3xAOJgUjXFzI3",
  "messageId": "-N6w8651yjmhOKRHd5xG",
  "phone": "+989034015019",
  "timestamp": "1657792676592",
  "toId": "0FXpksPdL4OAf9KAXx9B0R6nzmh2",
  "type": "1"
},
```

and this is my code in java script

```
firebaseDb.ref('chat/' + state.userDetails.userId ).push(payload.message)
```

but how i should get ky of my parent id  or push key before insert??

Answer (score 1):

The Firebase `push()` method can either be invoked *with* a payload, in which case it writes the payload to a new child in the database, or *without* a payload, in which case it returns a reference to a new child. Knowing that, you can do:

```
const newChildRef = firebaseDb.ref('chat/' + state.userDetails.userId ).push();
payload.message.pushId = newChildRef.key;
newChildRef.set(payload.message);
```

Also see:

- [Firebase: Can I combine a push with a multi-location update?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36774143/firebase-can-i-combine-a-push-with-a-multi-location-update/36774761#36774761)
- [When utilizing the .push method can I write a copy of the id to the object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34430978/when-utilizing-the-push-method-can-i-write-a-copy-of-the-id-to-the-object/34437786#34437786)
- [firebase: How to get a reference key for an object node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41408865/firebase-how-to-get-a-reference-key-for-an-object-node/41408929#41408929)

Comment: thank you so much mr.frank. that is true but i want know the Philosophy of this type of insert. do you see problem in design of this collection?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what you're asking there. In your original post you asked "how i should get [key] of my parent id or push key before insert?", and my answer here and the links show how to do that.

Comment: tankyou for your answer. my problem solved by your answer but i ask that why i should get key or pushkey in realtime db before insert! that is my personal ask  in one project that others designed.

Comment: Some devs like having the key inside the data too, so that they can get by with just using the value of a snapshot upon reading the data (so not using the key of the snapshot). I prefer not duplicating this part of the data, but (as you can probably tell from my phrasing) it's a preference and not a hard rule.